# Dynamics 365 Javascript - Return Value Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to discern if a user is a member of a certain team in Dynamics 365. I am using the following JavaScript functions to attempt this. My issue is that even though the getUserTeams is finding the user in the team when the result gets passed back to the calling function (UserHasTeam) the value is undefined. I feel like I am missing something here but for the life of me I don't know what. Can anyone help me?

```
function UserHasTeam(teamName) {
    ///<summary>
    /// Checks to see if the current user is a member of a team with the passed in name.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="teamName" type="String">
    /// A String representing the name of the team to check if the user is a member of.
    ///</param>
    var res;
    if (teamName != null && teamName != "") {
        // build endpoint URL
        var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
        var oDataEndpointUrl = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/";
        // query to get the teams that match the name
        oDataEndpointUrl += "TeamSet?$select=Name,TeamId&$filter=Name eq '" + teamName + "'";
        console.log(oDataEndpointUrl);

        // execute the request
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", oDataEndpointUrl, true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    console.log("Success");
                    result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log(result["d"]["results"][0]["TeamId"]);
                    res = getUserTeams(result["d"]["results"][0]["TeamId"]);
                    console.log(res);
                } else {
                    var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        };
        req.send(null);
        return res;
    }
}

function getUserTeams(teamToCheckId) {
    // gets the current users team membership
    var res; 
    var userId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId().substr(1, 36);
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var oDataEndpointUrl = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/";
    oDataEndpointUrl += "TeamMembershipSet?$filter=SystemUserId eq guid' " + userId + " ' and TeamId eq guid' " + teamToCheckId + " '";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", oDataEndpointUrl, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status == 200) {
                console.log("Success");
                result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                console.log(result["d"]["results"].length);
                if(result["d"]["results"].length == 1) {
                    res = true;
                } else {
                    res = false;
                }
            } else {
                var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling webapi request as Async and not sync.

```
req.open("GET", oDataEndpointUrl, true);
```

You should be calling it Sync like below

```
 req.open("GET", oDataEndpointUrl, false);
```

In addition, if you are using Dynamics 365 you should be using up to date webapi request.

Note: new webapi calls are in build Async and you should be using promise to make it sync.

Take a  look at this [retrievemultiplerecords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrievemultiplerecords)
and [retrieveRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrieverecord)

*Please mark it as solved if it helps*